# Allow individual users to blacklist certain companies

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Is it possible to blacklist a company not to be shown from Job search results?
I really liked the job results that I was getting until 50% of them became ads from Crossover. There's a separate topic about that company on meta, but my question is simple - would it be possible to add them to a blacklist?
Can you add that feature if it's missing?

### Update

I don't really like marking this as a duplicate. It's not really a duplicate since the core difference is being able to do so permanently vs ad-hoc. I can totally live with the other answer being accepted as a temporary solution to this one, but still the difference is pretty considerable! IMO this question should stay open until a decision either way is made.

Comment: Good question, we're discussing it now. In the short term you can filter companies out of the list using [-company:"Company Name"](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=-company%3A%22Company+Name%22)

Comment: There'd be a much simpler way to fix this: just don't accept any business from Crossover.

Comment: omg thanks ... that company ... -_-

Comment: I know that there are legitimate reason to avoid the company you've mentioned, and I think they should be called out personally.  But StackOverflow has repeatedly made it clear they don't like specific companies being called out like that.

I won't edit out the company name, but you may want to.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler if they don't like us calling out an unethical business they're continuing to have dealings with, they should edit out the references themselves.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Just take a look at the sheer number of upvotes to my question. If I understood correctly the core value of SO jobs was supposed to be developer friendly job search and not yet another LinkedIn or indeed or whatever. IMO for them it would be better to avoid controversial companies like this one and if for some reason they still prefer to do business with them at least give the users real ability to blacklist certain companies instead of instructing to use search syntax..

Comment: We're planning a feature that would allow you to save a job search, so you don't have to ad-hoc exclude Crossover from your searches.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting last years birthday gift from SO team!  So cool! (I asked this question on my birthday last year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was released a while back. You can exclude companies from appearing in your search results by going to your Job Preferences and adding the company to `Companies to Exclude`