# How to report recruiter spam on Jobs?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Stackoverflow's Jobs promises

> No recruiter spam
>
> You'll always know the hiring company when an employer messages you

but I just received a message from someone who offers to add me to his network of developers where he works together with several partner companies.

From the original german message

> Gerne lade ich dich in mein Berliner und Hamburger Entwicklernetzwerk ein, da ich mit verschiedenen Partnerunternehmen zusammenarbeite und Meet-ups für Entwickler organisiere.

English translation:

> I am happy to invite you in my Berlin and Hamburg Developer Network, as I work with various partners and organize meet-ups to developers.

For me this sounds like recruiter spam.

How can I report it?

---

Edit: Seems there is no way for reporting this.

Please add reporting abilities to messages coming through Jobs.

Comment: But... he wants to *network* with you! Have you no heart, man?

Comment: networking — so noughties-like. @Pekka웃

Comment: I say join his network and go to his meetups, bring a couple of big friends, eat all his food and drink his drinks.

Comment: not to forget the rockers to tear apart the meet up place at the end.

Comment: You're in Berlin; bring these dudes, wherever they hang out these days http://www.urbantravelblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/xbergmayday11.jpg

Comment: Oh, that's my neighborhood!

Comment: @Pekka웃 [Stay punk!](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1b/7c/f8/1b7cf830ddbaae698412c8408524037c.jpg)

Comment: Does the message you received link back to the company profile anywhere?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, no, it doesnt.

Comment: @Machavity. sure about what? I don't get it.

Comment: Was the message sent through careers? Maybe they found your email somewhere? (I'm not really familiar with how such messages in careers works.)

Comment: if I wasnt sure I wouldn't had ask this question. @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: Fair enough. I would have assumed a legit careers message from a company would include a link to the company's profile page. (And this did sound like a recent issue where people were receiving email outside of careers.)

Comment: Just be weary of the kind of brokers that hire you but then "loan" you out to another company to get a job done.  SE [does push their ads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers).  Like recruiters, they get a significant cut of your salary, a number you never see since the broker bills, takes his cut and pays you with what is left..  Unlike recruiters, they take this cut for as long as you work there.  Talk about money early so you don't waste too much time on what might well turn out to be a less than glamorous offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can email careers@stackoverflow.com and our support team will talk to the employer. Our team is currently assessing where a permanent feature might fit into our roadmap.

Comment: can I forward the original german message? Does somebody in the support team know German?

Comment: @vikingosegundo yes, please forward the original message.

Comment: @vikingosegundo There is something called google translate... ;) "
I am happy to invite you in my Berlin and Hamburg Developer Network , as I work with various partners and organize meet- ups to developers ." looks like an ok  translation to me. Oh wait... then again I don't know German! :D

Comment: @TJ: Thanks for translating this from my mother language to english.

Comment: It's been the better part of a year. Any progress on this other than "email us"? SE should be *the one place* I don't have to put up with recruiter bs.