# "No recruiter spam"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

> "No recruiter spam. You'll always know the hiring company when an
>   employer messages you."

That's what the banner in the top of the job page says. Yet the majority of vacancies are from Crossover, which is a body shop and not a real employer.

Am I the only one who feels that this isn't right?

Comment: I haven't encountered this company where I live, and I also haven't seen or heard of them spamming.  Is it the case that they are?  Or is it that their presence on the site is repulsive?

Comment: Crossover has been discussed several times

Comment: @Bart, and this "No recruiter spam" ad - was it discussed already?

Comment: @Makoto, they are the biggest poster of vacancies, at least in C#. And they aren't a real employer.

Comment: @user626528:  That would explain why I haven't heard of them; I'm firmly in the not-C# realm of jobs.  But I am curious what makes them not a real employer as opposed to other companies.

Comment: @Makoto, it's a body shop. They aren't the ones who pay you money.

Comment: see also: [SO careers should stop accepting business from predatory employers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers)

Comment: @gnat, this question is about SO's "No recruiter spam" policy - see the title.

Comment: agree, retracted my dupe vote. Your explanation for the difference is not particularly strong but in this case I am happy to pick anything that prevents close, to let us discuss this issue yet again

Comment: @Makoto, or because "These ads are targeted to exclude the EU and US."

Comment: So it's the case that their presence on the site is repulsive.  Okay then; what does that have to do with spam?  Have they been spamming you as a user?

Comment: There's **nothing wrong** with region-targeted ads.  Sometimes you need a developer to work exclusively in the EU; sometimes you need one to work exclusively in Japan.  What I'm trying to get at was the heart of the issue; if you feel like they're not a good company that's one thing, but if they're spamming that's quite another (and something that the SO Careers team should actively prevent).  From the earlier posts linked by @gnat, it seems like they're at least keeping an eye on them.

Comment: @Makoto, there are lots of wrong in a situation where a company posts lots of vacancies that don't represent work in _that company_ and the policy says "no recruiter spam".

Comment: **You haven't answered my question yet.**  Are they actively spamming users?  They *could* be a consultancy firm, but again I know very little details.  The main thing I'm trying to pin down is that your title and body seem to discuss spam in some capacity, yet all I'm finding are ethical debates about this company, which - don't let me take this way from you - are ***perfectly valid***.  But seriously, which is it?  Is this a spam issue, or an ethics issue?

Comment: @Makoto, spamming doesn't necessarily mean sending messages directly to users. **At all**.

Comment: I'll agree to disagree.  You and I have differing opinions on "spam".  Again, I'm fine with the ethical discussion about this company, but there's no reason to accuse them of spam unless they're actually spamming users.

Comment: @Makoto, they are spamming by posting **multiple** vacancies which aren't theirs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128229/discussion-on-question-by-user626528-no-recruiter-spam).

Comment: ^^^ upvoted comment about [move to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128229/discussion-on-question-by-user626528-no-recruiter-spam) not because I like the move but to indicate to other readers that discussion over there is worthy (quite a pity that [upvotes in such cases are ambiguous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279458/165773))

Comment: @rossipedia Wouldn't it be easier for stack to make a "Never show me a job from this employer again" button somewhere on Jobs?

Comment: @Magisch you can exclude Crossover from your search results using filters: https://goo.gl/bYFmsT

Comment: @Donna Yeah but does that also cover sidebar ads and suggestions? I'd like to have a "I really dislike this company and never want to hear from them again" button somewhere.

Comment: @Magisch agree, a global "dismiss" would be a better experience. If you don't mind creating a separate feature request, it'll help us to (hopefully) work this into our plans and keep you up-to-date on progress.

Comment: @Donna I made one, here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338003/global-dismiss-and-never-show-again-button-for-companies