# Is this Crossover fulltime remote job too good to be true?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

crossover.com provides a lucrative salary for techies like us from developing countries and admits to providing abroad projects to work on a full-time remote basis.

One such job posted: *https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/116011/full-stack-software-architect-60k-crossover*

Is it really believable?

Because I have read reviews on Quora that they just fail you at the end of the final code project submission and take your full working web application and sell it in the market.

Comment: It's really up to you to evaluate any given job offer and decide whether to apply, go through interviews, etc. Do your research on the company, to be sure, but Meta Stack Overflow (or Meta Stack Exchange) isn't the place to discuss specific employers' offers.

Comment: (Ehhh, sorry about any potential weirdness with notifications here. Your question got migrated here from MSE, deleted there, and then I tried clearing migration history since, even though this isn't the type of question we can handle, MSO is still the place to ask stuff about Stack Overflow Jobs. My bad.)

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the link you shared, it solved my issue. Crossover indeed is a shark

Comment: @Adam fairly sure I've seen a similar question regarding companies that were advertising to phish for cvs etc... but didn't have genuine jobs. I believe the reply may have been to contact the team with suspicions/evidence and someone would take a look. Would that not apply here?

Comment: @JonClements Good point. When in doubt, by all means - drop us a line via "contact us" at the bottom of the page and/or flag the job listing, and we will investigate any issues. (For the record: the link STEEL is referring to is this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332037). To me personally, though, this question doesn't read like a report of proven shady practices (certainly not any CV phishing) and instead reads more like "should I apply for this job?".

Comment: Crossover seems like an unethical employer, but it's not a fake company fishing CVs.

Comment: @AdamLear yes, my query is should I apply for this Job. Since it requires you to finish a 3 day code project and submit it. I don't want to waste mt 60hrs for free. Sorry for not being well descriptive in my post.