# Pretty harsh language in Job application rejection and Scam Jobs on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a job application in 2016 and the job application clearly mentioned the Visa Sponsor tag, but my application was rejected because they said they were looking for someone in the United States with pretty harsh words.

I have records of that in my emails somewhere and then there is a company which constantly posts jobs on Stack Overflow and everywhere else, and when you apply there they basically give you huge requirement test job for the work. Their [Glassdoor page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassdoor) is filled with these scam reviews. Can we flag these kinds of actions and does Stack Overflow take any action on them?

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264115/there-seems-to-be-a-fake-company-on-careers/264165#264165 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers

Comment: alinoudev.com - "...is a what"? It is just a big blue rectangle after *"what"* (at least with [JavaScript whitelisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)).