# Add (back) ability to edit job alerts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I occasionally edit my job alerts as I think of new criteria to make them more relevant.  It used to be that I could go to [my job alerts page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts), click an alert, and be taken to the relevant search page where I could edit it as needed.  However, in a recent update this ability was lost, so I now have to either recreate the search myself, or hope that it is still listed in my recent searches.

In addition, the above process is not ideal, especially when I have several alerts to modify.  What I would prefer instead is to see an Edit button next to the alert, which when clicked could display a form similar to the search form that allows me to edit the alert.

I might not need to edit my alerts as often if I could [blacklist companies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328192/2747593) or tags, but I think it could still be useful even in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. We plan to implement the ability to save searches so that you can easily access queries you use often without having to recreate them as well as opting in/out of email alerts for the query. Setting this as status-planned as we are planning to work on it as soon as time permits.

**Update**: We've added a feature so you can [save the searches you want](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366513/5516513), which also creates a job alert for you. You can manage saved searches and job alerts in the right hand sidebar.